# How to execute a .sql file into postgresql using java?

Tags: java, file, postgresql

I would liked to run a .sql file into postgresql using java. I've been able to do it in phpmyadmin but i guess it's not the same for postgresql. I didn't find anything that can help me out on the internet. Can someone please advice?

My .sql file CONTAINS :

```sql
Create Database IF NOT EXISTS Student;
```

This is what i've done in phpmyadmin and it did worked. So that's what am trying to do but this time using postgresql.

Here is my code for phpmyadmin: I've used IBATIS

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import org.apache.ibatis.jdbc.ScriptRunner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String script = "Entity.sql";
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        new ScriptRunner(DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", ""))
                .runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(script)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
 }
```

Can you please help?

Comment: It really depends on what's going to be in that file. If it's always just one statement, or if it's several statements which all end with a semicolon at the end of a line, you can do something about it. But if it's a file that's meant to be ran by psql, or has stored procedures in it or other stuff that may contain `;`, it's really not something you can do in JDBC. You may want to run psql in a subprocess.

Comment: No, it's going to be "several statements which all end with a semicolon at the end of a line"  What can u suggest to do this? @RealSkeptic

Comment: I've been able to do it in phpmyadmin! See the code below! I would liked to do same in postgresql... any advice? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: You mean you were able to do it in **MySQL**, not in **phpmyadmin** which is a web-based tool for accessing MySQL.

Comment: The fact is that i don't know what to put into the connection; For MySql it is ,   "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", "" , what about for the postgresql? what should i put instead for it to access it? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html

Comment: @RealSkeptic Do you have any idea?